# OpenStack Live Migration

Tags: openstack, libvirt, openvswitch

During live migration, the destination Compute Node has to perform some 'pre live migration' tasks, among them is the tap creation at the destination OVS.

I would like to know if once Nova creates such tap interface, is the port/tap status UP?.
This is the behavior I am experiencing, but I am not sure whether it is the default one or not?

In case it is, is it possible to delay such action to the 'post live-migrations tasks'. I am thinking of something like this

- Pre Live-migration : Create port/tap interface at destination Compute Node, but status DOWN
- Live-migration Post
- Live-migration : Delete
  port at source Compute Node, set port/tap interface at destination Compute Node UP

Thanks for your time

Best Regards,
Jorge Gomez